# SharePoint Online: Calculated field with week number starting Saturday

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I've found a few ways online to calculate the week number but none that allow me to start the week on Saturday. Here is the formula that I tested, but doesn't give me Saturday-Friday.

```
=INT(([Time In]-DATE(YEAR([Time In]),1,1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([Time In]),1,1)),"d")))/7)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could try below formula.

```
=ROUNDUP((Date1-DATE(YEAR(Date1),1,1)+1-(6-(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Date1),1,1)),"d"))))/7,0)+1
```

Test Data:

[image]